# Fast Report VCL how to change header and footer text in runtime

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I want to be able to change the text in frxReport according to user input. This is what I am doing but after saving to file the memo is empty in runtime and if I check the test.fr3 file after runtime it is unchanged

```
procedure TConfigForm.SaveReportBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MemoObj: TfrxMemoView;
begin
  VentsForm.frxReport1.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\GENERAL IT\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\TEST.fr3');
  // Access the report header band
  with VentsForm.frxReport1.FindObject('PageHeader1') do
  begin
    // Find the Memo object by name
    MemoObj := TfrxMemoView(FindObject('Memo1'));
    // Check if the Memo object was found and modify its text
    if Assigned(MemoObj) then
      ShowMessage('1');
    MemoObj.Text := MsgHeadEdt.Text;
  end;

  // Save the modified report back to the file
  VentsForm.frxReport1.SaveToFile('C:\Users\GENERAL IT\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\TEST.fr3');

  // Show a message indicating that the report data has been updated
  ShowMessage('Report data updated and saved successfully.');
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Did the program hit `ShowMessage('1');` statement? What was the value of `MsgHeadEdt.Text` at that point? Also note that `FindObject` method scans the report recursively therefore a single call to`VentsForm.frxReport1.FindObject('Memo1')` should be sufficient locate the object.